# Sample code for AES Encryption/Decryption using DirectCompute

Tags: encryption, directx, aes, hlsl, directcompute

would anyone happen to know of an implementation of AES Encryption/Decryption (any type) using DirectCompute (including the HLSL source code)?

I've read a few of the papers discussing AES on the GPU and they tend to make reference to either CUDA or OpenCL. I suppose learning to port those to DirectCompute could be a good exercise, but as it is non trivial, I wouldn't mind seeing how the HLSL is done correctly from the get-go.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can find an implementation in Direct3D 10 [here](http://code.google.com/p/amclibrary/)
It does not use DirectCompute, but if you know Direct3D, it should be straight forward to convert it to DirectCompute.